# Heat transfer between two fluids through a sandwiched solid (coupled problem)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

Two fluids ($t_h,t_c$) flow opposite to each other on either side of a solid ($T$), while exchanging heat among themselves. In such a scenario, the conduction in the solid is governed by:

$$x\in[0,1], y\in[0,1]$$

$$\kappa \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 T}{\mathrm{d} x^2} + \mu b_h(t_h-T) - \nu b_c(T-t_c)=0 \tag1$$

with boundary condition as $T'(0)=T'(1)=0$.

The fluids are governed by the following equations:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} t_h}{\mathrm{d} x}+b_h(t_h-T)=0\tag2$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} t_c}{\mathrm{d} x}+b_c(T-t_c)=0\tag3$$

The hot fluid initiates at $x=0$ and the cold fluid starts from $x=1$. The boundary conditions are $t_h(x=0)=1$ and $t_c(x=1)=0$.

Equation $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$ form a coupled system of ordinary differential equations.

It is pretty evident that using $(2)$ and $(3)$, Equation $(1)$ can be re-written as:

$$\kappa \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 T}{\mathrm{d} x^2} - \mu \frac{\mathrm{d} t_h}{\mathrm{d} x} + \nu \frac{\mathrm{d} t_c}{\mathrm{d} x}=0 \tag4$$
However, I have not been able to proceed further.

Some parameter values are $b_c=12.38, b_h=25.32, \mu=1.143, \nu=1, \kappa=2.16$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Calling $T_1 = T$ and $T_2=T'_1$ we have

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
T'_1\\
T'_2\\
t'_h\\
t'_c
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{\mu b_h}{\kappa}+\frac{\nu b_c}{\kappa} & 0 & -\frac{\mu b_h}{\kappa} & -\frac{\nu b_c}{\kappa}\\
b_h & 0 & -b_h & 0\\
-b_c & 0 & 0 & b_c
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
T_1\\
T_2\\
t_h\\
t_c
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. So, the system of differential equations has been converted to a matrix equation. Upon a little reading, I found that the next step should be to find the eigen values of the system using the characteristic equation right ? But I do not think a clean analytical solution will be possible in this case.

Comment: A formal closed solution is unlikely possible.